# Except bugando sem ser chamado

Tags: python, python-3.x, exceção

bom, fiz um "minigame" com até um sistema de salvar/carregar. o problema é que depois de salvar ou carregar o jogo, pedir pra "minerar", o script me retorna o comando do except do primeiro comando.

tipo:

> eu salvar, carregar, salvar. quando eu "minero" ele mostra o except do
>   primeiro save, se eu minerar dnv, mostra o except do "carregar", dnv
>   dai ele mostra o except do "salvar".

ou seja, mostra os except dos comandos em sequencia, mesmo a função não sendo chamada.

isso aconteceu dps de eu tentar implementar um valor pra minerar, tipo minerar 3 de uma vez ou 5. o "MinePower"

```
print('"jogo" ainda em desenvolvimento, relatar qualquer bug ao desenvolvedor\n')
tier1=0
tier2=0
MinePower=1
def setup(tier1, tier2,MinePower):
    tier1=int(tier1)
    tier2=int(tier2)

    print("--------------------------------------")
    print("| Melhorar     Minerar    Salvar     |")
    print("| Carregar     Inventario            |")
    print("--------------------------------------")

    acao=input()

    if acao=='melhorar' or acao=='Melhorar':
        if tier1>=9:
            tier1=tier1-9
            tier2+=1
            print('\nVocê comprimiu suas pedras, agora você tem',tier2,'Pedras Tier 2 e',tier1,'Pedras Tier 1.' )
            setup(tier1, tier2, MinePower)

        else:
            print("\nVocê não tem pedras suficientes.")
            setup(tier1, tier2, MinePower)

    elif acao=='minerar' or acao=='Minerar':
        tier1=tier1+MinePower
        print("\nVocê minerou",MinePower,"Pedra, agora você tem",tier1,"Pedras.")
        setup(tier1,tier2,MinePower)

    elif acao=='salvar' or acao=='Salvar':
        save(tier1,tier2,MinePower)

    elif acao=='carregar' or acao=='Carregar':
        carregar(tier1,tier2,MinePower)

    elif acao=='Inventario' or acao=='inventario':
        print("Pedras:",tier1)
        print("Pedras Comprimidas:",tier2)
        setup(tier1, tier2, MinePower)

    else:
        print("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=Comando desconhecido=-=-=-=-=-=-=-")
        setup(tier1,tier2,MinePower)

    setup(tier1,tier2,MinePower)

def save(SaveTier1,SaveTier2,SaveMinePower):

    try:
        SaveFile=open("Save.txt","w")
        SaveFile.write(str(SaveTier1)+'\n'+str(SaveTier2)+'\n'+str(SaveMinePower))
        print('Um Save nomeado "Save" foi criado')
        SaveFile.close()
        setup(SaveTier1,SaveTier2,SaveMinePower)

    except:
        print("Erro ao salvar arquivo")
        setup(SaveTier1,SaveTier2,SaveMinePower)

    setup(SaveTier1,SaveTier2,SaveMinePower)

def carregar(BackupT1,BackupT2,BCMinePower):
    try:
        CarrFile=open("Save.txt","r")
        CarrTier1=CarrFile.readline()
        CarrTier2=CarrFile.readline()
        CarrMinePower=CarrFile.readline()

        CarrFile.close()
        setup(CarrTier1,CarrTier2,CarrMinePower)

    except:
        print("Erro ao carregar arquivo, seu caminho ou nome podem ter sido modificados.")
        setup(BackupT1, BackupT2, BCMinePower)

    setup(BackupT1,BackupT2,BCMinePower)






setup(tier1,tier2,MinePower)
```

Comment: A função setup() está a ser chamada duas vezes.

Comment: mas o except que esta sendo chamado n está no setup

Comment: Em cada função você chama o `setup` três vezes. Está certo isso? Você chama dentro do `try`, dentro do `except` e depois fora do bloco `try/catch`, o que implica que a função `setup` será executada pelo menos duas vezes a cada chamada de uma das funções. Isso não parece fazer sentido.

Answer (score -1):

consegui resolver, não faz muito sentido mas consegui.
no começo do script, dentro do setup, eu defino os tier1=int(tier1) e o mesmo com tier2.
só fiz o mesmo com o MinePower.